# saving matlab image with contours plot on it

Tags: image, matlab, output, contour

I want to save an image with contours drawn on it in its original dimension.

say I have a 250x250 image, and I draw my contours (also 250x250) on it, I can't seem to get it to save at the original dimension of the image.

right now here's what I have

```
iptsetpref('ImshowBorder','tight');
himg = imshow(myimage);
hold on;
contour(contour1, [0 0], 'b','LineWidth',4);
contour(contour2, [0 0], 'y','LineWidth',2);
hold off;
```

if I save this image with

```
saveas(himg, filename);
```

I will get a super large 1200x900 image with white borders on left and right, how do I change the settings so that output file has the same dimension as my input image without the ugly white borders around it?'

I can't use papersize because image handle cannot access figure functions, and gca options don't affect window size to remove the side borders

Comment: What about using `gcf` with `papersize`, as opposed to `gca`?

Comment: Have you tried `imsave` instead of `saveas` (needs image processing toolbox)

Comment: imsave doesn't work because it only saves the image, not the figure with contours drawn over the image. I remembered trying gcf, and I think I got an error or something, need to try that again.